# Select all result from first table without matching with second table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join, average

I have 2 tables one is  user table and another is rating table which have the mapping data of user rating

**user table**

```
user_id |  firstname | lastname
--------------------------------
1       | 1test      | 1test lname
2       | 2test      | 2test lname
3       | 3test      | 3test lname
4       | 4test      | 4test lname
5       | 5test      | 5test lname
```

**rating table**

```
user_id |  rating
------------------
1       |   4
2       |   3
3       |   5
1       |   4
```

In result i need avg value of rating with user info in one query

```
user_id |  firstname | lastname      | rating
---------------------------------------------
1       | 1test      | 1test lname   |  4
2       | 2test      | 2test lname   |  3
3       | 3test      | 3test lname   |  5
4       | 4test      | 4test lname   |  0
5       | 5test      | 5test lname   |  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your query,

```
SELECT ut.*,AVG(rt.rating)as rating 
FROM user_table ut
INNER JOIN rating_table rt ON ut.user_id = rt.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

This is query you can use this to find average of all rating of all user

```
SELECT u.*, IFNULL(AVG(rating),0) as rating 
FROM user u 
LEFT JOIN rating r
ON u.user_id = r.user_id
GROUP BY r.user_id;
```

Comment: It is giving only one user who's rating is present in rating table but I need all the users from user table with 0 rating if there no entry of that user in rating table.

Comment: sorry, use the LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN and ratting get null so get 0 use IFNULL(AVG(rating),0). I have edited use this @avinash Mulewa

Answer (score 1):

Use **LEFT JOIN** to fetch all records from **user** table and matching records from **rating** table.

Try this:

```
SELECT u.user_id, 
       u.firstname, 
       u.lastname, 
       AVG(IFNULL(r.rating, 0)) AS rating
FROM `user` u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN rating r ON u.user_id = r.user_id 
GROUP BY u.user_id, u.firstname, u.lastname;
```

Comment: Thank You, This is what i want.

Comment: @AvinashMulewa You're most welcome... If you got your desired result then accept the answer by clicking on true sign which takes you to your desired result.